# Slow action in Rails application: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, newrelic

According to NewRelic the slowest transaction in my application is:

> Middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call

It takes about 261 ms app server time.

What is this `RouteSet#call`? Rails routing mechanism? Is 261 ms a normal value? How to speed it up?

Comment: I am facing very similar problem. Which rails version you're using?

Comment: @hardy12: 4.0.4 and there is no chance to upgrade: too many changes should be done to make the app work on 4.1.

Comment: I am running rails 3.2.17. And as you mentioned that you're facing it in 4.0.4 version, then there no sense to upgrade my app as well. Is it a post request or get request ?

Comment: @hardy12: I would like to know it too. That is my question about. It seems that it is some kind of system call.

Comment: I have this issue as well.  I have yet to debug completely, but it turns out that newrelic is mis-categorizing some of the controller actions.  The ones that show up as "Middleware/Rack/ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call" in NR are actually calls to some other controller in my app.  Haven't figured out why they all get clumped here...

Comment: @JordanMoncharmont What leads you to believe that NR is mis-categorizing those controller actions as RouteSet#call when they should be something else?

Comment: Any updates on this? Am having exactly the same problem. I'm running on rails 4.0.13.

Comment: Ditto for me. On rails 4.2.1.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. Anyone had any insight? We are on performance dynos already.

Comment: @Paul, did you find the solution to it?

Comment: @anusha: No. I am sorry about that. Also I have put the Rails things to the side for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `rocket_pants`.  Its controllers don't inherit from `ActionController::Base` so it was showing up in newrelic as middleware.
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/middleware-call-shown-as-web-transaction/25861/8

Answer (score -1):

If by any chance you are using the "Treat" gem, remove it. Seems like a bug.

https://github.com/louismullie/treat/issues/84

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.